# showing taxonomy (tags) in alphabetical order on nodes

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I just noticed that my tags are appearing at the bottom of my posts in the order I entered them, not in alphabetical order. I'm sure this is something simple, but I can't figure out how to get them to display on my nodes in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind, you can try to reorder taxonomy tags in vocabulary in alphabetical order.
Perhaps there is a better solution...

Comment: Thanks. I went into my taxonomies and clicked on the resort to alphabetical (which they already were). Nothing. the tags still appear as they were entered on the nodes and in the teaser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will work but it does seem rather complex for what we are trying to achieve:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  switch ($node->type) {

    case 'article': // Replace with your content type.

        $tags = array();
        // Loop over values.
        foreach($node->content['field_tags'] as $k => $v) { // Replace your field name.
            // We only want the ones with numeric keys (that actually contain tags)
            if(is_numeric($k)) {
                // Add this to the $tag array using the name as a key.
                $tags[$v['#title']] = $v;
                // Unset from the content array.
                unset($node->content['field_tags'][$k]);
            }
        }
        // Now sort by the array keys.
        sort($tags, SORT_STRING);
        // And add back into the content array.
        $node->content['field_tags'] = array_merge($node->content['field_tags'], $tags);

        // Phew!

        break;
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks. where would I put this code?